# calculate new left and top when scaling on rotated div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this div, in an absolute position

```css
div
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  -ms-transform: rotate(40deg); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  z-index:1;
}

div.resized
{
  width: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="resized"></div>
```

Now, when I set its width to be 200px,
the top and the left moves up and aside from 
its original point.

can someone please tell me how do I calculate the distance of this movement?

Comment: May we ask why you need to know the new position because it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey paulie
i have an object thay I making rotatable and re-sizable from all sides.

when i try to resize from the right, an object that is now rotated,
its not resizing only from the right, it also moves the div up and aside.

i want to know how can i calculate this movement in order to set it back  to its original location

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pivot point to be the top left, you should set your `transform-origin` accordingly.

Change your existing

`transform-origin: 50% 50%;`

to

`transform-origin: left top;`

You'll need to rearrange the positioning a bit to get a similar effect to the one presented in your original snippet, but now the rotation should work as you expected.

```css
div
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  -ms-transform: rotate(40deg); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  z-index:1;
}

div.resized
{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="resized"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer,
the thing is i have to keep the origin centered, 

is there are formula to find the new top and left when it is centered?